# Knockout subscriptions - synchronization among many clients with websockets

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, websocket, race-condition

Rather than posting the actual complex code I am posing this question in simplified form.  I am developing a web application that has multiple clients connected via websockets, each having interfaces that are programmed front end with knockout.

Each client has a variable called gameState which is an observable.  For simplicity's sake lets just say that its a regular number.

```
var gameState = ko.observable();
```

When the client initially connects, the current value of gameState is given to them by the backend server through a function called loadState.

```
function loadState(newGameState) {
    gameState(newGameState);
}
```

Each client is then able to change the value of gameState via an input box, which needs to send an update to all of the other connected clients.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: gameState"/>
```

I currently am sending changes by way of subscription.

```
gameState.subscribe(function(newGameState) {
    // sends a websocket message to the server with newGameState
    // which is received by all other clients via loadState function
});
```

The issue with this setup is that when the other clients get the websocket signal to update their own local values of gameState, this will in turn trigger their own gameState.subscribe function since the value was updated, thus sending out their own updates.  Obviously this causes an infinite and exponential cascade of updates and messages.

I feel like the solution to this is to change the loadState function to somehow pause the gameState subscription

```
function loadState(newGameState) {
    // pause gameState.subscribe
    gameState(newGameState);
    // re-enable gameState.subscribe
}
```

However there does not seem to be a way to accomplish this in knockout.

Additionally if someone does have a solution similar to "pausing the subscribe" as I pose above. I feel like there is a chance then of missing an update.  Say, loadState begins to run and gameState.subscribe is paused.  The user then enters a new value for gameState.  If they did it before gameState(newGameState) was executed, then their new value gets immediately replaced when gameState(newGameState) runs.  If they do it after the setting of gameState from loadState, then their value stays, but the subscription isn't active, so their new value will not be sent out to the other clients.

Comment: If an update to an observable does not change its value, it should not notify its subscribers. If your `newGameState` is a simple number, you don't have a problem. If it is an object, though, you need to test whether it represents a real change before doing the assignment.

Comment: What if you don't subscribe to the changes of gameState but rather you fire an event after you inputted the gameState (e.g. blur), this way if the other clients received the gameState then there will be no subscription that will fire.

Comment: Hi, Another option is to have sendState and receiveState. Your sendState will be fire when there's an update using InputBox or triggered using button. Then receiveState will only update the gameState of the receiver. for that sulotion you will enable Single Responsibility in your code.